# Postgres SUM returns 0 rows when columns don't exist. COALESCE and ISNULL don't work

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Using Postgres 9.5.

I'm trying to get the SUM of a user's submitted links votes. Think Reddit karma, SO etc.

It works perfectly for user's with submitted `links` , but when the user does not have any `links` then I get 0 rows in my response.

Is this a problem with the SUM(links.votes) or with the inner join? I'm quite new to SQL so I might be going at this from the wrong angle.

My query is as follows:

```
SELECT
users.firstname,
users.lastname,
users.email,
users.created_on,
SUM(links.votes) AS sum 
FROM users
INNER JOIN links 
ON users.id = links.created_by 
WHERE users.id = 50 
AND links.created_by = 50 
GROUP BY users.firstname, users.lastname, users.email, users.created_on
```

I've also tried doing `COALESCE(SUM(links.votes), 0) AS sum` thinking that it would return 0 in the 'sum' column, but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `left join`:

```
SELECT u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, u.created_on,
       SUM(l.votes) AS sum 
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     links l
     ON u.id = l.created_by AND
        l.created_by = 50 
WHERE u.id = 50 
GROUP BY u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, u.created_on;
```

Note that the condition on the `links` table goes in the `ON` clause rather than the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You rock. Works perfectly. Thanks, very basic answer I guess! Appreciate it. Have a great weekend :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need the **LEFT OUTER JOIN** and you must be able to handle NULL, the result of SUM in the case of not existing votes. 
You can use **CASE** to make your statement return 0 instead of NULL.